# Word to describe when you feel that there is so much going around you that you need to stop time to explore everything

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe a person's feelings when visiting a city for the first time, or a beautiful and lively park. There's so much going on that they would like to stop time to explore everything.

Sample sentence: When visiting Paris for the first time, I was so ___ with all the sights and sounds that I just stood there until it was time for the coach to leave.

Comment: Hello, welcome to English Language and Usage SE! I advise taking the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a feel for how the site works. The goal of this site is to provide detailed answers to questions about English. Because of this, questions are expected to provide detail and context to make it easier for other users to write good answers.

Comment: Your question is hard to answer because you aren't very specific about what kind of word you want. You want a word to describe a feeling. Do you want a noun for that feeling? An adjective to describe a person experiencing this feeling? An adjective to describe the thing that caused that feeling? Please provide an example sentence with a blank space where you would like to use this word. You should also look over the [question checklist for single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). You can  add details to your post by clicking the "edit" button.

Comment: I've edited your question to better fit the guidelines. I've tried to retain your original intent. Please feel free to [edit] further or to roll back to your previous version.

Comment: *overwhelmed* ?

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for ***enthralled*** (or one of the synonyms below).

Sample sentence:

> When visiting Paris for the first time, I was so ***enthralled*** with all the  sights and sounds that I just stood there until it was time for the
>    coach to leave.

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/enthrall?q=enthralled):

> **enthrall** (also British **enthral**)
>   *VERB* (enthralls, enthralling, **enthralled**)
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** Capture the fascinated attention of:
>
> she had been so enthralled by the adventure that she had hardly
>   noticed the cold
>
> On the way here, she had been enthralled, mesmerised, spellbound by
>   the area.
>
> **Synonyms**: captivate, charm, enchant, bewitch, fascinate, beguile, entrance, delight; win, ensnare, absorb, engross, rivet, grip,
>   transfix, hypnotize, mesmerize, spellbind

Answer (score 1):

I would say: "I had to pause, stand back and **orientate** myself when I first visited New York's vast Central Park for otherwise I would have lost my way and overlooked its fascinating fauna and flora".

Orientate: (BE) **Relate to setting or determining direction or position, either literally of figuratively. (Merriam-Webster online)**

Comment: And what make of vehicle are we driving tonight?

Comment: @RichardKayser  Alas, only one in my dreams. A mid-60's Ferrari (make, brand & marque all rolled into one), the iconic 275 GTB (model)  which was a track-racer masquerading as a road car! It would have to be Italian racing red in color of course, with a tan leather interior and Borrani wire wheels (specification). Alas, I have awoken from my dream and shall make do with my humble Honda, a 12-year old SUV, the "kind" of vehicle that's pretty boring to drive but never breaks down. Ho-hum!

Answer (score 1):

The word you are describing is **wonder** or **wonderment**.

From Merriam-Webster:

> [**wonder**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wonder): rapt
>   attention or astonishment at something awesomely mysterious or new to
>   one's experience
>
> [**wonderment**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wonderment): a feeling of being surprised or amazed

I prefer the former in response to the question, but the latter is a wonderful but underused word.

Answer (score 0):

You can also say you were *enamored* of Paris and its many sights.

> *enamored 1.1* Have a liking or admiration for: She was truly enamored of New York

- I became totally enamored of the flowers there.
- I'm really enamored with/of this part of the country.

Answer (score 0):

How about **awe**?

> When visiting Paris for the first time, I was so **awed** by all the
>   sights and sounds that I just stood there until it was time for the
>   coach to leave.

From Merriam-Webster:

> **awe**: an emotion variously combining dread, veneration, and wonder that is inspired by authority or by the sacred or sublime
>
> I expected to be impressed by Machu Picchu, but now that we're here,
>   standing in the clouds atop the world, I'm more than impressed—I'm in
>   awe. Machu Picchu is actually better than photographs suggest, more a
>   timeless way station than archaeological ruin. —Patrick J. Kelly,
>   Traveler, May/June 2005

Answer (score 0):

> **overwhelm**
>
> *verb (transitive)*
>
> 1. to overpower the thoughts, emotions, or senses of

[[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overwhelmed?s=t)]

This fits quite well: there's a lot going on which is overpowering your senses (sight, smell, hearing etc.) and your emotions.

> When visiting Paris for the first time, I was so **overwhelmed** with all the sights and sounds that I just stood there until it was time for the coach to leave.

Answer (score 0):

I like *enthralled* and voted it up.  However, I have to say that it is a bit fancy, and you might like another word, *overwhelmed* better, because it is more common, and in the context it means pretty much the same thing.

> When visiting Paris for the first time, I was so **overwhelmed** with all the sights and sounds that I just stood there until it was time for the coach to leave.

(I have one more suggestion, but it's a little old-fashioned: I was so **taken** with all the sights etc.)